# Save and load Smart Card Certificate

Tags: c, certificate, smartcard, cryptoapi

I need help on sending certificate information from one program to another, and logging into Windows with that information through the use of [CredMarshalCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374801(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LogonUser](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/SmartCardLogon.cpp). My program currently passes credentials and logs in successfully with a regular username/password combination. I'm just adding the ability to do it with Smart Card credentials.

I've used this [example](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/SmartCardLogon.cpp) successfully to login with a Smart Card Certificate.

This works when you run the program as the user, but not when trying to run the program as SYSTEM. This is because SYSTEM cannot access the user's "MY" store. I'm trying to work around this, either by passing the cert or the entire cert store to the program running as SYSTEM from an application running as the user.

I've tried numerous approaches to get something that would login successfully after serialization, but haven't gotten anything to successfully work. The approach that seems to work the best has been to call [CertSaveStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376567(v=vs.85).aspx) and Open the BLOB. I've used the last example at the bottom of this [Microsoft Example Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382035(v=vs.85).aspx). This restores the cert store from the BLOB correctly, finds certs, and even generates a username. But the generated username is different than the original generated username and fails to login with an error of ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE (The user name or password is incorrect).

My current test applications saves the cert and loads it again in the same program. I've taken the SYSTEM aspect out of the equation for now. I'm guessing the restored cert store is missing some information, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any insight would be appreciated.

One last note, I originally tried to just pass the generated username and PIN to SYSTEM and have it step down, but it failed with the same ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE error. I'm assuming the username has to be regenerated since being called by a different user/program, but that assumption could be wrong.

Comment: (I am no Win32 internals expert): Can't you use `CryptAcquireContext` with a specific container name as mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/03/03/how-to-select-which-smart-card-reader-to-perform-actions-on/) to access the smartcard objects? Then use the certificate to log in. Side note: your "example" link points to `LogonUser` documentation.

Comment: [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404289(WS.10).aspx) description is interesting as well.

Comment: @vlp Thanks for the comments. I fixed the example link. I've been looking into CryptAcquireContext, and I definitely need to understand it better. I'm continuing to dig into documentation to try and get a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten my example program working with `CertSerializeCertificatesStoreElement` and `CertAddCertificateContextToStore`. I am able to serialize the certificate, and add it to a new store in memory at a later time. I had tried this earlier, but accidentally did not save the size of the serialized item, I just tried to use `sizeof()` the item which returned an incorrect size.

If anyone is looking to send certificate credentials between programs in the same userspace this approach will work well.

I took this ahead step further and implemented it in my userspace/SYSTEM paradigm. The logic worked correctly, and I was able to generate a username but still failed to `LogonUser`. After another week or trial and error, I found a solution that works between the userspace and SYSTEM. I ended up having to use [LsaLogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378292(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `LogonUser`.

If anyone is looking to have a userspace program send credentials to a daemon running in SYSTEM and have that program step down to the user use this [example](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon.cpp). I initially tried this [very similar example](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon2.cpp), but it continues to fail. In the working example, you do not need to pass in a domain or username, just the PIN. The system will read the Smart Card from the reader and verify with the passed in PIN. This solution will work across computers, ONLY IF the smart card is located at the remote computer. I am looking into a way to accomplish having it work with the smart card in the host computer, but it is outside of this post.

I hope this saves someone the weeks of work I put into getting to this point.